# How to use a hidden Boundfield in a GridView in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, boundfield

I am binding a GridView using a DataSource in asp.net, and i would like to have some hidden BoundFields so I can access those values in my RowDataBound Function. However, when I set Visible="False" on these BoundFields the values do not get set and are always blank in the RowDataBound function.

Is there a way to do this? I've seen some suggestions of setting the style on the BoundField to hidden but this did not work for me either. Ideally I don't even want a column created in the gridview, I just want these values to be hidden so I can access them. Thanks!

Comment: Work directly with `e.Row.DataItem`. A second option would be to use invisible TemplateFields.

Comment: I assume you've tried this with everything the same except `Visible="True"`, right? I'm not sure why the BoundField wouldn't still be accessible.

Comment: sorry it took me so long to respond guys, wasnt able to check over the weekend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide a column (GridView) but still access its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376278/how-to-hide-a-column-gridview-but-still-access-its-value)

Comment: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Hide-a-column-in-GridView-and-still-access-its-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `DataItem` from the `GridViewRowEventArgs` passed to your `RowDataBound` method?

Like:

```
protected void MyGridView_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        // do something with rowView["myHiddenField"]
    }
}
```

[Check MSDN here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx)

Comment: i was previously using             if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            { string Name = e.Row.Cells[5].Text; } which may have been why it didnt work

Answer (score 2):

Odd, How are you doing it? I know I've done this before using:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ColumnName")%>'/>
```

Comment: From the OP description, it sounds like he's using <asp:BoundColumn DataField="myHiddenField" Visible="false" />

Comment: Possibly, I'm just saying, I've had success with this in the past.

Answer (score 2):

For this i will suggest you to use DataKey.

Pls refer this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/Data_presentation.aspx

eg:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
```

DataKeyNames="emp_id,Code">

```
int EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]);
  int DepartementID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[1]);
```

in DataRow bound:

```
((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Geetha