# How to hide a column (GridView) but still access its value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hide

I have a GridView with a `DataSource` (SQL Database). I want to hide a column, but still be able to access the value when I select the record. Can someone show me how to do this?

This is the column I want to hide and still want to access its value:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Outlook_ID" HeaderText="OutlookID" />
```

I tried everything to hide the column (property `Visible="false"`), but I can't access its value.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Hide-a-column-in-GridView-and-still-access-its-value

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, `GridView` does not hold the values of `BoundColumns` that have the attribute `visible="false"`. Two things you may do here, one (as explained in the answer from V4Vendetta) to use `Datakeys`. Or you can change your `BoundColumn` to a `TemplateField`. And in the `ItemTemplate`, add a control like `Label`, make its visibility false and give your value to that `Label`.

Comment: This hides the column but it doesn't hide the Column header. How will you do that?

Comment: Just add <HeaderStyle CssClass="hidden" /> in your boundfield.  And define a css style like this:   .hidden { display:none; }

Comment: Hiding the column header along with the column is a huge part of this. If you do not hide it, all the columns shift out of place. Thanks!

Answer (score 90):

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Accessing GridView Hidden Column value </title>
<style type="text/css">
  .hiddencol
  {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email ID" DataField="EmailId" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" >
</asp:BoundField>

ArrayList EmailList = new ArrayList();
foreach (GridViewRow itemrow in gvEmployeeDetails.Rows)
{
  EmailList.Add(itemrow.Cells[YourIndex].Text);
}
```

Comment: See http://www.netomatix.com/development/GridViewHideColumn.aspx for an in-depth explanation of this solution.

Comment: This solution has the added advantage that the data is still accessible in javascript on client side also. Should be the preferred solution to this problem!

Comment: You are a legend!

Answer (score 47):

Define a style in css:

```
.hiddencol { display: none; }
```

Then add the `ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"` and the `HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"` attribute to the grid field:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: This is a much more effective answer

Answer (score 38):

**You can use DataKeys** for retrieving the value of such fields, because (as you said) when you set a normal `BoundField` as visible false you cannot get their value.

In the `.aspx` file set the `GridView` property

```
DataKeyNames = "Outlook_ID"
```

Now, in an event handler you can access the value of this key like so:

```
grid.DataKeys[rowIndex]["Outlook_ID"]
```

This will give you the id at the specified rowindex of the grid.

Comment: DataKeys where meant for that

Comment: How would this work if you were using DataSource controls with CRUD code in the HTML...?

Answer (score 26):

You can do it programmatically:

```
grid0.Columns[0].Visible = true;
grid0.DataSource = dt;
grid0.DataBind();
grid0.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

In this way you set the column to visible before databinding, so the column is generated.
The you set the column to not visible, so it is not displayed.

Comment: Not working at all, I get ArrayOutOfBoundsException when I place that code in a Panel PreRender method.

Comment: Worked for me simple and easy.

Comment: This is by far the best answer.

Answer (score 12):

If you do have a `TemplateField` inside the columns of your `GridView` and you have, say, a control named blah bound to it. Then place the `outlook_id` as a `HiddenField` there like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OutlookID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="blah" runat="server">Existing Control</asp:Label>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenOutlookID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Outlook_ID") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now, grab the row in the event you want the `outlook_id` and then access the control.
For `RowDataBound` access it like:

```
string outlookid = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("HiddenOutlookID")).Value;
```

Do get back, if you have trouble accessing the clicked row. And don't forget to mention the event at which you would like to access that.

Answer (score 9):

You can make the column `hidden` on the server side and for some reason this is different to doing it the `aspx` code. It can still be referenced as if it was visible. Just add this code to your `OnDataBound` event.

```
protected void gvSearchResults_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;

    if (gridView.HeaderRow != null && gridView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count > 0)
    {
        gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[UserIdColumnIndex].Visible = false;
    }

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSearchResults.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[UserIdColumnIndex].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. For everyone looking you need to make sure both the header column and the grid view column are hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Leave visible columns before filling the `GridView`. Fill the `GridView` and then hide the columns.

Answer (score 2):

I have a new solution hide the column on client side using **css** or **javascript** or **jquery**.

```
.col0
{
  display: none !important;
}
```

And in the aspx file where you add the column you should specify the CSS properties:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address Key" DataField="Address_Id" ItemStyle-CssClass="col0" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col0" > </asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to get the value of a hidden column in a `GridView` that is set to `Visible=False`: add the data field in this case `SpecialInstructions` to the DataKeyNames property of the bound GridView , and access it this way.

```
txtSpcInst.Text = GridView2.DataKeys(GridView2.SelectedIndex).Values("SpecialInstructions")
```

That's it, it works every time very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I used a method similar to user496892:

```
SPBoundField hiddenField = new SPBoundField();
hiddenField.HeaderText = "Header";
hiddenField.DataField = "DataFieldName";
grid.Columns.Add(hiddenField);

grid.DataSource = myDataSource;
grid.DataBind();

hiddenField.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution, an elegant(IMO) quick 2 parter.

1.
On your gridview, add a column as normal, no need to do anything differently:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AccountHolderName" HeaderText="Account Holder" 
 ReadOnly="true"/>
```

You can keep the header text if this is useful to you for later processing.

2.
In the rowdatabound method for the grid hide the header, footer and row for that column index:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
    e.Row.Cells[10].Visible = false;
}
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
    e.Row.Cells[10].Visible = false;
}
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{                                   
    e.Row.Cells[10].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it code behind.

`Set visible= false` for columns after data binding .
After that you can again do visibility "**true**" in **row_selection** function from grid view .It will work!!

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot but no luck. The most of them was working with some errors. Finally I used this code and it worked for me.
probably you should change 1 to some other value. for me I would hide second col.

protected void FoundedDrGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

```
    if(e.Row.RowType!=DataControlRowType.Pager)e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just set the width to 0. and it works.

```
columns.AddFor(m => m.Id).Name("hide-id").Width(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

When I want access some value from `GridView` before `GridView` was appears.

1. I have a `BoundField` and bind `DataField` nomally.
2. In `RowDataBound` event, I do some process in that event.
3. Before `GridView` was appears I write this:

   ```
   protected void GridviewLecturer_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   {
       GridviewLecturer.Columns[0].Visible = false;
   }
   ```