# Why ID is empty, picked from Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Why deviceID is empty, I am filling it from SP. At backend it gives perfect result and even fill Gridview perfectly but at .cs level it creates problem

```
Select DeviceID, TerminalSNO, SoftwareVersion from Transport.Devices
```

it gives perfect result but in asp.net it picks `""` from gridview

GV:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridviewDevicesBulkUpdate" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="DeviceID" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DeviceID" HeaderText="DeviceID" Visible="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TerminalSNO" HeaderText="Serial No." ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SoftwareVersion" HeaderText="Software Version" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Includes ?">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBoxIncludes" Text="." CssClass="checkbox checkbox-danger" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

.cs

```
foreach (GridViewRow Row in GridviewDevicesBulkUpdate.Rows)
{

    CheckBox chkUpdate = (CheckBox)Row.Cells[3].FindControl("CheckBoxIncludes");
    if (chkUpdate.Checked == true)
    {

        string DeviceID = Row.Cells[0].Text.Trim();

        if (ManageTransport.ManageDevices.UpdateAllDevices(IsCardPwdUpdated, SoftwareVersion, IsActive, int.Parse(DeviceID)))
        {
            Response = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Response= false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Row.Cells[3].FindControl("CheckBoxIncludes");` but `Row.FindControl("CheckBoxIncludes");`. The `GridViewRow` is the `NamingContainer` of the `CheckBox`.

Comment: but it throws error at  string DeviceID = Row.Cells[0].Text.Trim();

Comment: that was not meant as a solution(then i would have answered) but as a suggestion. Instead of a `BoundField` i would use a `TemplateField` with an invisible label that text has the `DeviceID`. Then you could use `(Label)Row.FindControl("LblDeviceID")).Text`

Comment: oh yes ok, lemme check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the reason is that you use an invisible `BoundField`. You can read about it here:

[Retrieve data from visible false BoundField of Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486372/retrieve-data-from-visible-false-boundfield-of-gridview)

So you could either follow the suggestions there or use a `TemlateField` with a label:

```
<Columns>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <Label runat="server" ID="LblDeviceID" Text='<%# Eval("DeviceID") %> ' Visible="false"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TerminalSNO" HeaderText="Serial No." ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SoftwareVersion" HeaderText="Software Version" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Includes ?">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBoxIncludes" Text="." CssClass="checkbox checkbox-danger" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Then you can retrieve the value in codebehind in following way:

```
Label lblDeviceID = (Label)Row.FindControl("LblDeviceID");
string DeviceID = lblDeviceID.Text;
```

Meanwhile i'm always using `TemplateFields` because you could use any html there and you don't run into such issues. They are simply more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Add `RowType` of `GridView` e.g `if (Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)`

```
CheckBox chkUpdate = (CheckBox)Row.FindControl("CheckBoxIncludes");
```

your code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow Row in GridviewDevicesBulkUpdate.Rows)
 {
    if (Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
    CheckBox chkUpdate = (CheckBox)Row.FindControl("CheckBoxIncludes");


     if (chkUpdate.Checked == true)
        {
         string DeviceID = Row.Cells[0].Text.Trim();
         if (ManageTransport.ManageDevices.UpdateAllDevices(IsCardPwdUpdated, SoftwareVersion, IsActive, int.Parse(DeviceID)))
         {
           Response = true;
         }
         else
         {
         Response= false;
         }
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is not necessary. If you use `GridviewDevicesBulkUpdate.Rows` only rows are returned which `RowType` is `DataControlRowType.DataRow`. You get the header or footer only in `RowCreated` or `RowDataBound`. This is documented in the  [`GridView.Rows`-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): _"Only rows with their `RowType` property set to `DataControlRowType.DataRow` are stored in the Rows collection. The GridViewRow objects that represent the header, footer, and pager rows are not included in the collection."_