# Entering each row of datagrid into SQL database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to take a column from each row of my datagrid and enter it into an SQL database. Having all sorts of problems/errors making it work.

This is the most current version:

```
For i = 0 to agentGridView.Rows.Count - 1
    varAgt = agentGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblAgentVisitAgents (VisitID, AgtID)" & _
        " Values (" & _
        VisitID.Text & "," & _
        varAgt & ")"
    strSQL = Utils.replaceChars(strSQL)
    DAL.ExecNonQuery(strSQL, CommandType.Text)
Next
```

EDIT: The issue is that my cell(1) is a hidden field. When I make it visible, the entry form works. When it's hidden, it won't enter anything and thus gives me a syntax error. Is there a way I can use a hidden field for entry purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I went with:

Front:

```
<asp:GridView ID="agentGridView" DataKeyNames="agentName,agentValue" ... />
```

Back:

```
For i = 0 to agentGridView.Rows.Count - 1
    varAgt = agentGridView.DataKeys(i).Values("agentValue").ToString

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblAgentVisitAgents (VisitID, AgtID)" & _
        " Values (" & _
        VisitID.Text & "," & _
        varAgt & ")"
    strSQL = Utils.replaceChars(strSQL)
    DAL.ExecNonQuery(strSQL, CommandType.Text)
Next
```

Source (for C#): [Hide BoundField's but still be able to get values with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413700/hide-boundfields-but-still-be-able-to-get-values-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Text` instead of `Value` . Like following.

`varAgt = agentGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text` instead of `varAgt = agentGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value`

But if you have that control in a `Label`, then you need to typecast to label and then use Text. E.g.

`varAgt =  CType(agentGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).FindControl("controlID"),Label).Text` -- replace `controllID` with required label id.

Source - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-get-Selected-Row-cell-value-from-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: This worked. However, the issue is now that my cell(1) is a hidden field that I want to use. Showing it makes it work. Hiding it throws a syntax error.

Comment: Checked your updated question, my reply = when you make it hidden , by `visible = false` , there will not be any element added to HTML, so you won't be able to get by `cells(1)`, my suggestion would be to make it just hidden by setting attribute `display:none`, then only you will be able to get it using code.\

Comment: Added my own answer, but yours helped me get there. Thank you very much.