# Copy value from in a GridView into a TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have a `GridView` from where I want to get a text value from cell in column 26 in the selected row into an `TextBox` (named `txtResult`). Cell is not visible (its `Visible` property is `false`).

I tried this:

```
txtResult.Text = grdMyGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[26].Text;
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you have `TemplateFields` or `BoundsFields`? If the former, show your aspx especially the controls.

Comment: so,what is the problem?

Comment: I can get the text when I do Visible=true, but i can get the Value on Visible=false

Comment: Does this helps [How to hide a column (GridView) but still access its value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376278/how-to-hide-a-column-gridview-but-still-access-its-value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the invisibility on the regular column properties on the code behind (.aspx), do it throught the RowDataBound event. I believe this way you will get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You'll better try this code:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ColummName"].Value.ToString();
```