# Datatable selected Columns

Tags: c#

I have a data table with 9 columns in it. I want to display 3 columns of my selected choice by giving the column name in datagrid view 1 and other in data grid view 2. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: how do you want to select columns ? By user input or hard coded ?

Comment: i have this filled datatable with 9 columns i want to display for e.g person name ,address,phone number in gridview 1 and others in 2.

Comment: ok. is it your web application or window application ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide a column (GridView) but still access its value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376278/how-to-hide-a-column-gridview-but-still-access-its-value)

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
   DataView view = new DataView(dt1);
   DataTable dt2 = view.ToTable(true, "FirstColumn", "SecondColumn", "ThirdColumn");
```

**Regard

Ali Muhammad**

Comment: I hope it works for you :)

Comment: Are you sure there is any overload accepting those arguments? I've just checked it and there is not any matched overload.

Comment: DataView view = new DataView(dt1);
   DataTable dt2 = view.ToTable(true, "FirstColumn", "SecondColumn", "ThirdColumn");

Comment: But **it's different** in your code, can't you see that? You should update in your code.

Answer (score 2):

DataGridView has methods with which you can set visibility of the columns. Bind the gridviews to same datasource and hide the columns you want in respective grids:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

or

```
dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;
```

You can try something like this:

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 0, 2 };
foreach (int ColIndex in arr1)
    dataGridView1.Columns[ColIndex].Visible = false;
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 1, 3 };
foreach (int ColIndex in arr2)
    dataGridView2.Columns[ColIndex].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Second would be better. I would suggest that first. `dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;` :)

Comment: @RJK - depends on requirement. See my edit.