# Data GridView C# hide a column at run time

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a datagridview name is "grdShowDeatils", a class with name "objShowCampaignStats" having method which returns a DataTable name of method is  "GetCapmaignsStatsDetails()"

```
{
grdShowDeatils.DataSource = AnyDataTable;
}
```

My Problem is `dataTable` has three columns , i want to hide 2nd column at run time it should not be visible for user. How i can do this ?

Comment: try the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819247/gridview-hide-column-by-code?rq=1

Comment: well you can just say the other to columns should be collapsed  take a look here this might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819247/gridview-hide-column-by-code                                                                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376278/how-to-hide-a-column-gridview-but-still-access-its-value                                            http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/256498/Gridview-Column-make-visiable-true-and-false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this

```
{
    grdShowDeatils.DataSource = objShowCampaignStats.GetCapmaignsStatsDetails();
    grdShowDeatils.Columns[1].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write the following code

```
{    
    grdShowDeatils.DataSource = objShowCampaignStats.GetCapmaignsStatsDetails();
    grdShowDeatils.Columns[3].Visible = false;
}
```

or

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: @AHMAD SUMRAIZ oh no I have added your expecting answer as first.But you are accepting someone answer

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your DataTable returns below three columns ,

Name , Address , Phone No. And you want to hide Address Column

At `.aspx` page you can bind DataGridView as per the below,

```
<asp:DataGridView ID ="grdShowDeatils" runat="server">
 <Columns>
  <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Name" DataFeild="Name"/>
  <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Address" DataFeild="Address" Visible = "False"/>
  <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Phone No." DataFeild="PhoneNo"/>
 </Columns>
</asp:DataGridView>
```

OR

You can code at `RowDataBound` event of DataGridView as per below,

```
protected void grdShowDeatils_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   e.Rows.Cells[1].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is asp.Net Web Forms--can't you just set grdShowDeatils.autoGenerateColumns = "false" and then just specify the 1st and 3rd columns (via the designer or programmatically)?