# Get value of specific column while editing a Gridview when boundfield is set to false

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

How to get the value of some specific cell on editing a gridview when boundfield is set to false.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewInvoice" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" DataKeyNames="DOID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
    Width="100%" BorderStyle="Solid" Style="overflow: auto" OnRowDataBound="GridViewInvoice_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridViewInvoice_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="GridViewInvoice_RowDeleting">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tax1" Visible="false" HeaderText="Tax1" SortExpression="Tax1" HeaderStyle-Width="7%" ItemStyle-CssClass="colHidden" HeaderStyle-CssClass="colHidden" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ReadOnly="false" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you mean.. you want the value to be visible when you update gridview

Comment: use this line of code in code behind.. start counting from 0 and determine what number the column is, then just do this replacing # with the number you came up with.

`myGridView.Columns[#].Visible = True`;

Comment: no...when i update the value i want to get that value to a variable

Comment: use column index in place of # to get the value of whatever column you want (in your case hidden column). `protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
    string s=GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[#].Text;
    
  }`

Comment: see this link.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10680513/9650643

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the `BoundField` value in GridView if its visibility is set to `Hidden`. Instead, Add a `HiddenField` and access that in GridView Edit Event.

Add the below as a GridView Column

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewInvoice" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" DataKeyNames="DOID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
    Width="100%" BorderStyle="Solid" Style="overflow: auto" OnRowDataBound="GridViewInvoice_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridViewInvoice_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="GridViewInvoice_RowDeleting">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tax1" Visible="false" HeaderText="Tax1" SortExpression="Tax1" HeaderStyle-Width="7%" ItemStyle-CssClass="colHidden" HeaderStyle-CssClass="colHidden" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ReadOnly="false" />
       <asp:HiddenField ID="Tax1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Tax1") %>'/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-Behind

```
protected void GridViewInvoice_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)GridViewInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tax1");

  if (hf != null)
  { 
      var value = hf.Value;
  }  
}
```

Alternatively, you can also get the value with [DataKeyNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames?view=netframework-4.7.2) if you have specified one in the `GridView`.

> Gets or sets an array that contains the names of the primary key
>   fields for the items displayed in a GridView control.

Something like this,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewInvoice" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Tax1">
<Columns>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="Tax1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Tax1") %>'/>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then this to get the value,

```
protected void GridViewInvoice_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    var value = GridViewInvoice.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["Tax1"].ToString();
}
```