# When Adding or removing rows with TemplateField in asp.net the datatable is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, datatable

I have two columns for every columns I want to remove All the BoundField columns and keep the TemplateField columns. I followed the instruction on this website https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-with-CheckBox-Get-Selected-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx however I alredy had a table but with TemplateField instand of BoundField. I want to be able to use my old table and remove the boundField from my table.

Here is a image of what I want to remove in red.
[image]

Here is where my table looks like

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPrimaryGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" onrowdatabound="gvPrimaryGrid_RowDataBound"
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="compras_id"
                 OnRowCommand="gvPrimaryGrid_RowCommand"  OnRowEditing="gvPrimaryGrid_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvPrimaryGrid_RowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowUpdating="gvPrimaryGrid_RowUpdating"  CellPadding="3" AllowUserToResizeColumns="True" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" onsorting="gvPrimaryGrid_Sorting"  GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
                <PagerSettings  Mode="Numeric"  />         
                <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"  runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" OnCheckedChanged="chkRow_CheckChanged" />--%>
                       <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkRow_CheckChanged" />
                           <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />--%>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" Width="20px" Height="20px"/>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" Width="20px" Height="20px"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ToolTip="Update" Width="20px" Height="20px"/>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" Width="20px" Height="20px"/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/addnew.png" runat="server" CommandName="AddNew" ToolTip="Add New" Width="20px" Height="20px"/>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>   

                    <asp:BoundField DataField = "compras_id" HeaderText="Compras ID"  HtmlEncode="false"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField = "numero_contrato" HeaderText = "Numero contrato" HtmlEncode="false" /> 
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="marca" HeaderText="Marca" HtmlEncode="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="designacion" HeaderText="Designacion"  HtmlEncode="false"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="tipo" HeaderText="Tipo"  HtmlEncode="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="referencia" HeaderText="Referencia"  HtmlEncode="false"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="plazo" HeaderText="Plazo"  HtmlEncode="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre_proveedor" HeaderText="Proveedor"  HtmlEncode="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="cantidad_requerida" HeaderText="Cantidad requerida"  HtmlEncode="false"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="cantidad_pedida" HeaderText="Cantidad pedida"  HtmlEncode="false"/> 

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Compras ID" SortExpression="compras_id" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>                       
                        <asp:Label DataField="compras_id" HtmlEncode="false"  ID="lblPurschaseID" CssClass="gridTextbox" Text='<%# Eval("compras_id") %>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <%--<EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="txtType" Text='<%# Eval("tipo") %>' runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>--%>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox  CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="txtPurschaseIDFooter" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>    
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Numero contrato" >
                    <ItemTemplate>                       
                        <asp:Label DataField="numero_contrato"  HtmlEncode="false"  ID="lblContractNumber" CssClass="gridTextbox" Text='<%# Eval("numero_contrato") %>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>   
                <asp:DropDownList  ID="drGridContractID" Runat="server"  AutoPostBack="false"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDown_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                          <%-- <asp:TextBox CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="txtSupplier" Text='<%# Eval("nombre_proveedor") %>' runat="server" />--%>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox  CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="txtContractNumberFooter" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to change the AddRow and Remove row so it works with templatefield instead of the BoundField

```
private DataTable AddRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
    {
                                                        // gvRow.Cells[1].Text
        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("compras_id = '" + gvPrimaryGrid.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text+ "'");
        if (dr.Length <= 0)
        {
            int i = 1;
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["compras_id"] = gvRow.Cells[i++].Text;
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["numero_contrato"] = gvRow.Cells[i++].Text;
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["marca"] = gvRow.Cells[i++].Text;
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["designacion"] = gvRow.Cells[i++].Text;
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["tipo"] = gvRow.Cells[i++].Text;
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["referencia"] = gvRow.Cells[i++].Text;
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["plazo"] = gvRow.Cells[i++].Text;
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["nombre_proveedor"] = gvRow.Cells[i++].Text;
            //dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["cantidad_requerida"] = gvRow.Cells[i++].Text;
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["cantidad_pedida"] = gvRow.Cells[i++].Text;
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["cantidad_entregada"] = gvRow.Cells[i++].Text;
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
        return dt;
    }

    private DataTable RemoveRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
    {                           
        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("compras_id = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");
        if (dr.Length > 0)
        {
            dt.Rows.Remove(dr[0]);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used labels to in add method instead of gvRow.Cells[i++].Text and the code works as I wanted.

```
private DataTable AddRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
{
    String purchasesID = gvRow.Cells[1].Text.ToString();

    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("compras_id = '" + purchasesID + "'");
    if (dr.Length <= 0)
    {

        Label brand = gvRow.FindControl("lblBrand") as Label;
        Label numero_contrato = gvRow.FindControl("lblContractNumber") as Label;
        Label designacion = gvRow.FindControl("lblDesignacion") as Label;
        Label type = gvRow.FindControl("lblType") as Label;
        Label reference = gvRow.FindControl("lblReference") as Label;
        Label paymentDeadline = gvRow.FindControl("lblPaymentDeadline") as Label;
        Label supplier = gvRow.FindControl("lblSupplier") as Label;
        Label deliveredQuantity = gvRow.FindControl("lblDeliveredQuantity") as Label;
        Label requestedQuantity = gvRow.FindControl("lblRequestedQuantity") as Label;

        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["compras_id"] = purchasesID;  
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["numero_contrato"] = numero_contrato.Text; 
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["marca"] = brand.Text; 
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["designacion"] = designacion.Text; 
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["tipo"] = type.Text;
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["referencia"] = reference.Text; ; 
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["plazo"] = paymentDeadline.Text;
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["nombre_proveedor"] = supplier.Text; 
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["cantidad_pedida"] = requestedQuantity.Text; 
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["cantidad_entregada"] = deliveredQuantity.Text; 
        dt.AcceptChanges();
    }
    return dt;
}
```